# Error writing XML Document to file in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am trying to write `org.w3c.dom.Document` to a file. I get the `Document` from

```
String URL = "http://...."
DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();
Document doc = null;
try {
    parser.parse(new InputSource(URL));
    doc = parser.getDocument();
} catch () {}
```

Then I write this `Document` to a file using

```
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(file));
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

While doing this I keep getting the following error

```
ERROR:  'Namespace for prefix 'xlink' has not been declared.'
```

What might be wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a different library such as [Dom4J](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net) rather than trying to fight your way through the built-in XML API in Java. Dom4J is better designed and makes your code much more readable:

```
Document doc = new SAXReader().read(inputStream);
new XMLWriter(outputStream).write(doc);
```

None of this mucking around with `FactoryFactoryFactoryFactories`.

I know this doesn't directly answer your question but hopefully it will help anyway. Dom4j knows how to talk to the Java XML API so you can mix and match them to suit your needs. You can even plug it into Xalan or something similar if you want to use XSLT.